# WP_QUERY order posts by two combined meta_value dates

Tags: wp-query

The query needs to grab from thousands of posts based on two custom fields. 'Original Date' is required for each post, with 'Featured Date' being optional (hidden based on a custom checkbox field. When checked, featured_date is set to original_date by default). However, if 'Featured Date' is set for a particular post, it should be priority and ultimately sorted by the featured date as if the original date was set to equal the featured date.

That is, the query does NOT need to sort all posts by featured date first, & then original date. Instead, it needs to sort them together as if those dates were combined into a single column. So a user could push the event to the top of the results by setting a featured date, but once another post is created with a later original date, the featured date post falls from the top.

**Example database:**

```
ID | post_title |    meta_key   | meta_value
---------------------------------------------
1  | Person 1   | original_date | Jan 2nd
2  | Person 2   | featured_date | Jan 1st
2  | Person 2   | original_date | Dec 1st
3  | Person 3   | featured_date | Jan 3rd
```

**Expected query results:**

```
ID | post_title |    meta_key   | meta_value
---------------------------------------------
3  | Person 3   | featured_date | Jan 3rd
1  | Person 1   | original_date | Jan 2nd
2  | Person 2   | featured_date | Jan 1st
```

And if a new post with an original (or featured) date of say Jan 4th is created, it would now be at the top of the results.

I've looked into meta_query, and can get the posts based on if those custom fields exist for a given post. But I haven't been able to find a way to order them such that the dates from both fields are combined and ordered, rather than ordering all by one field first then the other.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'        => 'custom_post_type',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'paged'            => $paged,
  'meta_query'       => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'featured_date',
      'type' => 'DATE',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'original_date',
      'type' => 'DATE',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
  ),
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  // 'orderby' => array('meta_value_date' => 'DESC')
);

$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am able to get the results I want from the below SQL query (albeit likely inefficient as I don't know much about SQL). However, the issue with using this SQL query is there is already logic that adds additional arguments to the initial query based on other factors. I would have to re-implement adding to the SQL query based on that logic, which I'd like to avoid by figuring out the proper wp_query way of doing this.

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT *, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS sort_date
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id )
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'featured_date'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT *, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS sort_date
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id )
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_date'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
) AS created_table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY sort_date DESC");
```

---

**Edit** - birgire's response made me realize it's worth mentioning this is for a plugin that is already being used in production on numerous sites. The current functionality orders the posts by 'original_date'. But it's been requested to allow the user to push certain posts to the top, while still respecting the queue (ie, later posts will be above it). The featured_date is the requested functionality.

Answer (score 0):

On post insert/update, set the post's `menu_order` as the **maximum of the numeric `MMDD` values** of `original_date` and `featured_date`. Maybe set the menu order in the format `1MMDD` to avoid a leading zero.

Then we can **order the custom type posts by the menu order** very fast with:

```
WP_Query( [ 
   'post_type' => 'custom_post_type', 
   'orderby'   => 'menu_order', 
   'order'     => 'DESC' 
] );
```

where `menu_order` is a `int(11)` column in the [posts table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts).

If not all of the custom type posts have these custom dates, group them e.g. by a **custom taxonomy**, to use in your `WP_Query`. Maybe one could instead look for posts with non-zero menu order.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have mentioned that this is a feature for a plugin that is already being used on numerous sites. Currently the posts are ordered by the 'original_date', but it's being requested that there be a way to push posts to the top temporarily, but have those posts still respect the queue. I've pitched setting/unsetting the post as sticky, so it's temporarily pushed to the top, but this is the requested functionality. I'm thinking it might be necessary to update the DB (it's a multisite) setting feature_date equal to original_date for all the posts, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: I've solved the issue, but not by altering the query, as I still couldn't figure out a viable solution. Instead, I added an additional field (actual_date). So when the 'feature_post' toggle is unchecked, only the 'original_date' shows. When it's checked, both 'actual_date' & 'featured_date' show. The query remains the same, and instead, I used the 'save_post' hook to set the 'actual_date' equal to the 'featured_date' if both the toggle is true & 'feature_date' isn't empty. The 'actual_date' will be used for the frontend when the toggle is checked.

Comment: One can hook into the update/insert process to set the menu order and one could sync the menu orders for the existing installs with a script. Meta queries can be slow but if you still want to go with the UNION query (not sure how it solves your problem though), I've experimented with combining multiple WP_Query [here](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries).